# Something goes wrong when I prepare to contribute to EGit on Eclipse, I can't finish the downloading process

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, jgit

There is the site for EGit Contributor:
[Egit/Contributor Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/Contributor_Guide/)

With following the Automated Developer Setup, I finish almost steps and I insatlled  Eclipse Photon successfully. And when the IDE start, it will engage startup tasks. Then, I got all files except a small file named 'egit-4.6'. Here is the info of it:
[Info of egit-4.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uLaF.png)

I clicked the 'Finish' to download the file, but there are exceptions as follows:

```
Executing startup tasks
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_181-b13
Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.committers.latest.released
Workspace C:\Users\24541\egit-master\ws
Project org.eclipse.egit.master
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.git 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.projects 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.workingsets 1.9.0.v20180529-0916, build=3551, branch=5a7202105cdec0e9bc9553799ba330ea58714ce5
Performing Target Platform egit-4.6
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20180606145124/repository/
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170919201930/repository/
Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/
ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems occurred while resolving the target contents
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:151)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems loading repositories
    ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems loading repositories
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.4.8.v20171121.
      java.io.IOException: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.4.8.v20171121 is not a valid repository location.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getQueryableMetadata(P2TargetUtils.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.IUBundleContainer.getRootIUs(IUBundleContainer.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getRootIUs(P2TargetUtils.java:1361)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.resolveWithSlicer(P2TargetUtils.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.synchronize(P2TargetUtils.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition.resolve(TargetDefinition.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
    ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems loading repositories
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core code=1002 Unable to read repository at file:/C:/Users/24541/egit-master/ws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/compositeContent1035882654.xml
      java.io.IOException: 外部 DTD: 无法读取外部 DTD 'xhtml1-transitional.dtd', 因为 accessExternalDTD 属性设置的限制导致不允许 'http' 访问。
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeRepositoryIO.read(CompositeRepositoryIO.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getQueryableMetadata(P2TargetUtils.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.IUBundleContainer.getRootIUs(IUBundleContainer.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getRootIUs(P2TargetUtils.java:1361)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.resolveWithSlicer(P2TargetUtils.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.synchronize(P2TargetUtils.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition.resolve(TargetDefinition.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
      Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 外部 DTD: 无法读取外部 DTD 'xhtml1-transitional.dtd', 因为 accessExternalDTD 属性设置的限制导致不允许 'http' 访问。
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeRepositoryIO.read(CompositeRepositoryIO.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getQueryableMetadata(P2TargetUtils.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.IUBundleContainer.getRootIUs(IUBundleContainer.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getRootIUs(P2TargetUtils.java:1361)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.resolveWithSlicer(P2TargetUtils.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.synchronize(P2TargetUtils.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition.resolve(TargetDefinition.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
        ... 1 more
    ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems loading repositories
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core code=1002 Unable to read repository at file:/C:/Users/24541/egit-master/ws/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache/compositeContent75883547.xml
      java.io.IOException: 外部 DTD: 无法读取外部 DTD 'xhtml1-transitional.dtd', 因为 accessExternalDTD 属性设置的限制导致不允许 'http' 访问。
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeRepositoryIO.read(CompositeRepositoryIO.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getQueryableMetadata(P2TargetUtils.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.IUBundleContainer.getRootIUs(IUBundleContainer.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getRootIUs(P2TargetUtils.java:1361)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.resolveWithSlicer(P2TargetUtils.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.synchronize(P2TargetUtils.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition.resolve(TargetDefinition.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
      Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 外部 DTD: 无法读取外部 DTD 'xhtml1-transitional.dtd', 因为 accessExternalDTD 属性设置的限制导致不允许 'http' 访问。
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.persistence.CompositeRepositoryIO.read(CompositeRepositoryIO.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getQueryableMetadata(P2TargetUtils.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.IUBundleContainer.getRootIUs(IUBundleContainer.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getRootIUs(P2TargetUtils.java:1361)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.resolveWithSlicer(P2TargetUtils.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.synchronize(P2TargetUtils.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition.resolve(TargetDefinition.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
        ... 1 more
    ERROR: org.eclipse.pde.core code=0 Problems loading repositories
      ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/.
      java.io.IOException: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/ is not a valid repository location.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:767)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getQueryableMetadata(P2TargetUtils.java:907)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.IUBundleContainer.getRootIUs(IUBundleContainer.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getRootIUs(P2TargetUtils.java:1361)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.resolveWithSlicer(P2TargetUtils.java:1128)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.synchronize(P2TargetUtils.java:761)
        at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.TargetDefinition.resolve(TargetDefinition.java:368)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.activateTargetDefinition(TargetPlatformUtil.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.pde.impl.TargetPlatformTaskImpl.perform(TargetPlatformTaskImpl.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3332)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3275)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4502)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2316)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4496)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4494)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3266)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3241)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3141)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)

Took 6 seconds.
There are failed tasks.
Press Back to choose different settings or Cancel to abort.`enter code here`
    enter code here
```

I'm so upset about this error, please someone can help me! Please!

Answer (score 1):

I find that the file 'egit-4.6' is a repository of Eclipse Neon, but my Eclipse is Photon.
Then, I installed Eclipse Neon and try to setup again. It works!

Comment: Good job figuring out on your own.